# Value isnt saved after inputstring on TDBWPRichText to linked MemoField

Tags: database, delphi, rtf, delphi-xe5

i have a TDBWPRichText linked to a MemoField on my Database. 
when i press a Button i want the formated text to prepend some text.
the visual component shows the the prepended string, but when i Post, the Value of the memo doesnt change.

```
MyTable.Edit;
DBRichedit1.SelLength  := 0;
DBRichedit1.CPPosition := 0;
DBRichedit1.Inserting  := True;
DBRichedit.InputString('Test:' + #13);
//it shows the value on the component here 
MyTable.Post;
```

in the MyTableBeforePost the Field has the old value though apparently

```
Field.Value <> Field.OldValue
```

If i enter text manually it works just fine

i also tried to save it manually (where the comment is) but the String is the old value

```
DBRichedit.SaveToString(MyTable.FieldByName('MyMemo').AsString,False);
```

Is there anyway i can get the prepended String into my Table?

Comment: You're trying to do something db-aware controls generally aren't designed to do; leave the DBRichEdit control alone.  You'll invariably get problems trying to force changes to a DB record by setting values in DB-aware controls - they will fight it all the way.  Instead, put the dataset into edit mode, prepend your string to the Field's AsString and then post the change.

Comment: well then i wont have the formatting made in the rtf

Comment: In that case, I would work out how to do what you want using a non-db-aware TRichEdit, then apply to to the field's data, not the DBRichEdit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours i resorted to the dev of WPtools and he promptly provided me with the answer which is incredible simple:
you have to call

```
RichEdit.Changing
```

before interacting with it within the code

Answer (score 1):

This was a lot trickier than I was expecting it to be, even though I recalled that working with RichText in Delphi code can be a bit of a pain.

Anyway, the following works for me, to add an Rtf header stored in a disk file; see if it does for you.  It isn't pretty and I can't help thinking that it's inordinately
long-winded.

```
procedure TForm1.InsertHeader;
// Prepend an RTF header to an existing RTF DB field
var
  TL : TStringList;
  ExistingText : String;
  RE : TRichEdit;
  MS : TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  TL := TStringList.Create;

  //  The reason for using a temporary RichEdit is to enlist its assistance
  //  in manipulating the rich text
  RE := TRichEdit.Create(Nil);
  RE.Parent := Self;
  try
    ExistingText := AdoQuery1.FieldByName('Memo').AsString;
    RE.Clear;

    //  The reason for using the richedit's SelText in the following is that my
    //  initial naive attempt to assign to its Lines.Text provoked a "Line Insertion Error"
    RE.SelStart := 0;
    RE.SelText := ExistingText + #13#10;
    TL.LoadFromFile('\d7\demos\richedit\header.rtf');
    RE.SelStart := 0;
    RE.SelText := RE.SelText + TL.Text;
    RE.Lines.SaveToStream(MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    AdoQuery1.Edit;
    TMemoField(AdoQuery1.FieldByName('Memo')).LoadFromStream(MS);
    AdoQuery1.Post;
  finally
    TL.Free;
    RE.Free;
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Btw, there is an answer to how to insert RTF into pre-existing RTF in a TRichEdit here:  http://delphidabbler.com/tips/57

Comment: thanks will try it out later. WPRichedit is from wptools http://www.wpcubed.com/products/wptools/

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be WPTools, but as google didn't seem to have heard of it, I didn't bother checking.